# Finding $g'(x)$ of the following.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So I need help solving the following question.

$$\int_3^{x^5} \sin(t^2)\,dt$$

I tried to do it and got $5x^4\sin(x^2)$, but the correct answer is $ 5x^4\sin(x^{10})$. Where did the $x^{10}$ come from?

Comment: Um, your title has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: $(x^5)^2=x^{10} $

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean that the integral expression is equal to $g(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know the leibnitz integral rule this question is a piece of cake .

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt = f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x).$$

Please show your solution also next time.

Comment: What I go was 5x^4sin(x^2, but thats not correct.

Comment: Alright but it is always better to show your attempt otherwise it would be marked as a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Write  $\displaystyle \int_3^{x^5} \sin(t^2)\,dt=F(x^5)-F(3)$

$F$ being an antiderivative of $f(t)=\sin(t^2)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

(note that $F'(t)=\sin(t^2)$ )

PS:

$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left( \displaystyle \int_3^{x^5} \sin(t^2)\,dt\right)=\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(F(x^5)\right)=5x^4F'(x^5)=5x^4\sin\left((x^5)^2\right)=5x^4\sin(x^{10})$